# Running Multiple Nodes with openMPI on Slurm

Tags: c, slurm, hpc, openmpi

I'm trying use OpenMPI and Slurm to run a simple hello world program. The goal is to use an #SBATCH script like below.

In the bashrc I added `%PATH` and `%LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and they both contain `/shared/centos7/openmpi/3.1.2/bin`

When I run the SBATCH script with `srun ~/hello-mpi.x` it's output is what I'd expect:
`Hello World from process 15 from the Node c0625. There are a total of 32 processes.`
`Hello World from process 15 from the Node c0626. There are a total of 32 processes.`

Two nodes 625 and 626, 32 processes like I have in the SBATCH script below.

When I run the SBATCH script with `mpirun ~/hello-mpi.x` I get this error:

```
An ORTE daemon has unexpectedly failed after launch and before
communicating back to mpirun. This could be caused by a number
of factors, including an inability to create a connection back
to mpirun due to a lack of common network interfaces and/or no
route found between them. Please check network connectivity
(including firewalls and network routing requirements).
```

And if I run the the SBATCH script with `srun mpirun  ~/hello-mpi.x` I get this error `slurmstepd: error: execve(): mpirun: No such file or directory`.

This is the SBATCH script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --verbose
#SBATCH --export=ALL
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=16
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --time=00:10:00
#SBATCH --job-name=JonsJob
#SBATCH --mem=100G
#SBATCH --partition=short

srun ~/hello-mpi.x
```

On the command line, if I run mpirun or srun I get output from a single node (i did not use salloc to request another node.) `Hello World from process 2 from the Node c0170. There are a total of 4 processes.`

But, if I use `srun mpirun ~/hello-mpi.x` I get en error `slurmstepd: error: execve(): mpirun: No such file or directory`

This is the code hello world code is below along with my.bashrc.

```
/* The Parallel Hello World Program */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int rank, size, namelen;
   char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
   
   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
   MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);
     
   printf("Hello World from process %d from the Node %s. There are a total of %d processes.\n", rank, processor_name, size);

   MPI_Finalize();
   return 0;
}
```

Also, I have environmental variables $PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my .bashrc file

```
# .bashrc
# Source global definitions

if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

module load openmpi
module load cuda/9.2
```

Answer (score 0):

See the SLURM FAQs below

[Loading User Environment](https://slurm.schedmd.com/faq.html#user_env)

Basically, .bashrc isnt loaded by slurm.

Either call the .bashrc file from your sbatch script of add your "module load" commands within your sbatch script.

Comment: This didn't work.  I am still getting the same errors.  do you have any other recommendation?